# Put the two images in single control in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to put the one image on left corner and another on right corner of Control(ex :button) and need click event for that.

please tell me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried?

Something like this should work but it depends on exactly what you're after:

```
<Button Click="myClickHandler">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="image1.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="None" />
        <Image Source="image2.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="None" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

*Disclaimer: the above is untested and written freehand. I make no guarantees of it compiling, etc.*